# Wordpress Underscores - ajax refreshing page instead of handling it right away?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, reload, underscores-wp

I just started using Underscores and I love it, but I noticed that when I use anything that requires ajax (like Contact Form 7), page will reload instead of handling it on the spot.

I've included jQuery with functions (even tried with plugin to do so) and while jQuery scripts works, I can never get page to NOT refresh.

Both wp_head() and and wp_footer() are present so it's not that.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Please check `console` maybe you have some `jQuery` error find and fix it or please attach a screenshot of your `console`.
Thank you

Comment: I'm just dumb, it was only when I tried to validate my html code I've noticed that I accidently commented footer (including body and html tag as well), I'm surprised everything worked at all...